# SQL Server Query: Concatenate Multiple Rows during a JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

This may have been mentioned here before, but I couldn't find an answer to the exact problem I'm trying to solve.
I am using SSMS 2018 v18.8 with SQL Server 2012 SP4.
My query requires querying multiple tables with joins.
One table (table 2) contains multiple values, and I'd like to return them in the query as a concatenated line.

[image]

How should I write my query to return the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you want the client application or reporting tool to roll up data like this. However, in Sql Server 2017 and later you can use the [`string_agg()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) (along with `GROUP BY`) to make this happen.

```
SELECT t1.System, t1.Location, string_agg(t2.User, ',') As [User]
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.System=t2.System
GROUP BY t1.System, t1.Location
```

Earlier versions need an [ugly `FOR XML PATH` query](https://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/).

Comment: Since I'm on 2012, I'm stuck with the ugly XML PATH

Comment: I got it working with the XML Path, but only when the data is Text. Here is my code:

    STUFF (( SELECT ',' + REPLACE (U.UniqueUserName, 'nm\', '') AS [text()]
     FROM v_UserMachineRelation U
     WHERE
     U.MachineResourceID = R.ResourceID
     FOR XML PATH('')
     ), 1, 1, '' )
     AS [Primary Username(s)]

But if the cell values contain integers, this fails trying to convert bigint to text. Does anyone know how to use the XML PATH query to accommodate the concatenation of integers?

Answer (score 0):

Very simple answer using US States and Counties, Counties table contains a key (StateID) identifying the State the County belongs to.

```
SELECT States.name, STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), ISNULL(County,'N/A')), ', ') AS Counties
FROM Counties
join States on Counties.StateID=State.ID
GROUP BY States.name;
```